# Maximum recursion depth exceeded with pyinstaller in Python?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

This is a common issue with certain libraries like `pandas`. I read that the solution may be by adding:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)
```

in the setup.py .Where is this setup file? I have created the py file and located it in the directory that i want to turn to exe but i don't know where i should add that piece of code?

There is also this fix:

```
hook-pandas.py
hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype',
'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime',
'pandas._libs.skiplist']
```

but I don't know how to make this hook even though I read the post in the official site. If you can, make a clear answer about how to solve this.

Comment: You can set it in any file. just run the file recursion limit will be updated

Comment: I should add this to the file with the code? the post said not the file with the code but the setup. I don't know, nothing changes if I place it with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need add it to any special file.
 Just add it into your current python file and run. You can see the difference by running `getrecursionlimit()` before and after running the command.

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())   # recursionlimit before 
# 1000
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000) 
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())    # recursionlimit after 
# 3000
```

Comment: I made a py with this. I ran it and then tried again to turn the other py to exe and it failed again. What is going on? it didn't change anything

Comment: I am sorry. This will only change in current context. Pardon.

Comment: Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: You place the above code in your current python file

Comment: I did it but didn't change anything. Also tried with the spec file with the same error.

Comment: I guess you have infinite recursion which is dangerous. You need to optimize your code so that it doesn't exceed the recursion limit.

Comment: This is a relevant post if you want to see the problem: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3422

Comment: But this is a different problem, isn't it?

Comment: The problem I think is from some libraries used in the code like pandas that can't work normal with pyinstaller and there are some things required to make it work and create an exe.

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` files are created by you, to define the packaging information used for your project. I'd strongly recommend reading [The Packaging Python Projects tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), as the topic is much larger than can be covered here.

All you do is add those lines to the top of your `setup.py` file, prior to any other imports (which might end up being monkeypatched by `Pyinstaller`, causing the problem).

Comment: How can I make it turn to exe and proceed without the error?

Comment: @user10026983: My understanding was that the error was at packaging time. You need to make your `setup.py` with the recursion fix, then follow the Pyinstaller docs for using it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked simply by adding the following lines at the beginning of the .spec file that pyinstaller creates:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

Comment: As the spec file you referenced during the process, when you add the code to that?

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answers by others for anyone attempting to increase the maximum recursion limit:

Use the
`import sys sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`
snippet in the my_code.spec file, not your my_code.py file. Additionally, this file is re-written every time you run the `pyinstaller` command on a .py file, thus once you have edited it after an unsuccessful run, running `pyinstaller my_code.py` will take you back to square one.

Instead, run `pyinstaller my_code.spec` to keep your latest recursion limit setting.